# Embedding part of a web site

Tags: html, embed, screen-scraping

Suppose I want to embed the latest comic strip of one of my favorite webcomics into my site as a kind of promotion for it. The webcomic has the strip inside of a div with an id, so I figured I can just embed the div in my site, except that I couldn't find any code examples for how to do it (they all show how to embed flash or a whole website). 
Can someone please show me (or tell) how it's done?

PS I'd rather not use server side scripting or external services (which is what is often recommended for embedding RSS).

Comment: Don't forget to ask the webcomic's author if they really want that first, though. And they might even have some “hidden” URL for you to include.

Comment: The fact that you'd "rather not use server side scripting or external services" is dumb - this is how you should be doing it if you really need to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update - Cross domain request with jQuery (on client side)

Yesterday I was browsing James Padolsey's blog, where he posted a great article, on how to do [cross domain request](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) with jQuery, also Chris Heilmann has a nice [DEMO](http://icant.co.uk/articles/crossdomain-ajax-with-jquery/error-handling.html).

The principle is to use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) -> a yahoo api for web page queries, where you receive a JSON with all the html. Happy scraping :)

### Scrape remote data with php, load with jQuery

What about considering simple **AJAX** call, that would intercept the comic element and update with its contents your `<div id="update-comic" />` primarily used for this purpose?

Also you will use a simple **php** to get the remote page, cause you cannot make ajax call on another domain

*note: user must have JavaScript enabled, also following code uses jQuery library*

### Putting it all together

1. on your page, where you want to display remote comic strip create a **div** only for this purpose, lets call it `update-comic`

   ```
   <div id="update-comic">
       <!-- here comes scraped content -->
   </div>
   ```
2. write down the **php**, call it `comic-scrape.php`, it will **download the html** from remote page, you should consider **caching the response** and updating it on a specified interval (e.g. 30min, 1hr, your call.. :))

   *server performance should not suffer after simple cache checking implementation*

   ```
   <?php
       $url = 'http://www.example.com/';
       $response = file_get_contents($url);
       echo $response;
   ```
3. now comes the **jQuery** magic, where you make ajax call on your php scraper and take only the relevant element you are interested in. Place this script inside your **view page** (where you have your `<div id="update-comic" />`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       // set all your required variables
       var 
           localUrl = '/comic-scrape.php',
           elementId = '#remote-comic-id',
           elementToUpdate = $('#update-comic');

           // update the local elementToUpdate with elementId contents
           // from your php in localUrl

           elementToUpdate.load(localUrl + ' ' + elementId;
   });
   </script>
   ```

I hope, I covered everything.

### Employing simplexml and xpath

As philfreo suggested in comment, a viable solution could also contain selecting the required id server-side. It is very easy with use of php's simplexml and a little xpath:

```
<?php

    // set remote url and div id to be found
    $elementId = 'remote-comic-id';
    $url = 'http://www.example.com/';

    // instantiate simple xml element and populate from $url
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
    
    // find required div by id
    $result = $xml->xpath("//div[id={$elementId}]");
    
    // take first element from array, which is our desired div
    $div = array_pop($result);

    echo $div;
```

Comment: If you're going to use your own PHP script to download/serve the file - you should just parse the comic in PHP as well instead of using the client side (jQuery) for this. There are plenty of libraries in PHP to easily access a certain node from HTML.

Comment: OP wants to be as resouse server friendly as possible.. I think this is one of the most easiest way to provide such a functionality.. Also it's extendable to parse the response html and cache only the relevant `#id`

Comment: @philfreo updated code, to reflect requirements of doing xml parsing server-side

Comment: Alright, I guess I don't have a choice but to engage in some server side scripting... Time to find a php tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible because you cannot manipulate iframe/frame content. Using iframe tag will just modify content in  tag, but not the src.
Neither with AJAX, because you have to be on the same domain.

So, for example, you can use PHP with cURL or quite simply with fopen.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use an `iframe`. The content isn't literally on that page, but it looks like it.

Here's an example: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

It looks like this:

```
<iframe src ="http://www.example.com/index.html" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: I know about the iframe, but how do I target a specific div? I don't want to embed the whole site, just the one div that has the strip.

Comment: You can't doesn't let you selectively trim out part of a page with an iframe.

Answer (score -2):

<embed src="url of your comic" width="300" height="250" />

Comment: This is used to embed flash objects

Comment: It is used to embed lots of things, but isn't valid, and doesn't let you selectively trim out part of a page.