# Loading iframe of specific portion of website

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to load a portion of external website content using jQuery and AJAX, as I have read that you can do this. I'd only like to load a portion of the website as explained in this post [iframe to Only Show a Certain Part of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page#answers-header) .

I have full copyright permission to the site I'm trying to load.
Thanks,
etrey

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: How to load only a portion of an external website, actually a specific external `<div>`, within an iframe or within a specific `<div>` @MateuszRogulski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can create a div in your main page

```
<div id='iframediv'>
</div>
```

Then in your JS code mention the following line

```
$('#iframediv').load('https://www.google.co.in #DIVNAME');
```

Here you have to replace `https://www.google.co.in` with the target URL. And replace `DIVNAME` with the **target div id** in the target page.

**UPDATE:**

This method will not work if you are accessing a page in different domain because of security issues. In that case you can do the following

1. create a `New Server-side Page (say GetContent.aspx)` in your web
   application (so that the domain will be same).
2. Then on server-side you can load the required page (from a different
   domain) and extract the required section. If you are not able to extract the section, load the complete page.
3. Then load this content to the `New Server-side Page (say
   GetContent.aspx)`
4. Now you can show this `GetContent.aspx` using `.load` function. If you are using the complete page (without extracting) then use the following code for loading the required content div.

   $('#iframediv').load('https://www.google.co.in #DIVNAME');

Comment: Can it be an external domain?

Comment: In case of external domains, you can do something as mentioned in the answer update

Comment: On the `GetContent` page would you reccomend an html iframe or the jquery `.load` method? @Wolf

Comment: Use `.load` method if you want to load the content at run time. If you want to load the content along with the page load, then `iframe` will be a simple option

Comment: Go figure `.load` on a `GetContent` page presents the same non-loading error because it is a different domain still. However, if I do a `.load` of a `<div>` I am not sure how that will work because the `iframe` code does not appear to pull in the `div`'s it just presents the page in a frame. This answer would work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176342/embedding-part-of-a-web-site#answer-2225401, however I had a problem scraping with styles. @Wolf

Comment: On `GetContent.aspx` page, you need to load the content using server side code. `C#/vb` if you are using ASP.net

Comment: I'm using PHP, do you know what that would look like? @Wolf

Comment: [embedding-part-of-a-web-site#answer-2225401](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176342/embedding-part-of-a-web-site#answer-2225401)
In this answer check the section "Employing simplexml and xpath"
Just copy paste the code. that should work

Comment: [link](http://goo.gl/alCFk) Getting a weird error with that code. Thank you for all of your help! @Wolf

Comment: Seems like the page you are using  (http://google.com/news) is not having a valid xml structure. It is possible because of the unstructured tags like <br> etc. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You state that this is an external website. If the website was within the same domain, you could use jquery's load method to do this

```
$('#iframediv').load('https://www.google.co.in #DIVNAME');
```

If the page is external, you won't be able to do that. You could look at the external page and see if there is a named anchor. If there is, you can use that anchor in the src of the iframe to cause the iframe to start out scrolled to that position. I don't think it will get you exactly what you want but it's the closest you will be able to get with the page being on an external domain.

```
<iframe src="http://externalsite.com/page.html#nameofanchor"/>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to use `.load` or a similar method to load a portion of a website in an iframe that is a different domain? @Wolf