# Unable to retrieve a div using JQuery load method from URL

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NiceDiv1").load("http://www.w3schools.com/jquery//ajax_load.asp");
});
```

This is not working for me.

Comment: have a look at [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) - your console should have an error message like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.w3schools.com/jquery//ajax_load.asp. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot load content of website from different domain name. you should use iframe for this

```
<iframe width="500" height="500" src="http://www.w3schools.com/jquery//ajax_load.asp"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks you very Much Mr. Pathan.. Futher, Acutally I want to load a specific div of a website into my page. so using iframe (http://www.hamariweb.com/islam/islamic-names.aspx?Page=2 .TextClass) TextClass is the class of that div i wanted to load into my page. but using iframe it's not working. Please comment :

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176342/embedding-part-of-a-web-site

Comment: u need to use php for that. and with php also you can not access some sites eg. goole,msn.

Comment: try this if it works or not
assign this id => "myiframe" to iframe and try to hide other div, make sure that you will not hide parent div of TextClass
$("#myiframe").contents().find(".TextClass").show();

Comment: Dera Pahtan.. I am a beginner.. If you write code here I will be really thankful to you. thanks

Comment: I just started learning Asp.net (c#). Its difficult for me to understand PHP in the same time. so please solve my problem using jquery asp.net c# limitations. thanks

Comment: Hey sorry i was busy, i dont know how to do this in c#, put another question with c# tag